# Show amount greater than 10000, where amount data type is string in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.transaction.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    "$match":
                    {"AMOUNT":{"$ne":null}}
                },
                {
                "$group":
                    {"_id":{}}
                },
                {
                    "$addFields":
                    {AMOUNT:{$toDouble:["$AMOUNT"]}}
                },
                {
                "$project":
                {"AMOUNT":{"$gt": 10000}}
                }
            ]
        );
```

Trying to fetch amount from the collection which is greater than 10000, as I'm working in MongoDB so data is in string format, so I'm using aggregation with $addFields parameter to change the string into the double and then apply the $gt function.

Tried multiple way by arranging query in group but not able to solve it.
Please help

Comment: your `$group` stage is not helping you. Why did you add it?

Comment: Look at this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/3PuacC_Xr84

Comment: @nimrodserok  That playground is the answer.   Please post it here as an answer.   SO policy is to put answers on SO and use IDE and playground links as secondary supporting resources.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        $toDouble: "$AMOUNT"
      },
      1000
    ]
  }
})
```

You can use same $expr in aggregation function inside $match

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $toDouble: "$AMOUNT"
          },
          1000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Per @Buzz Moschetti suggestion:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {$expr: {$gt: [{$toDouble: "$AMOUNT"}, 10000]}}}
])
```

Or:

```
db.collection.find(
  {$expr: {$gt: [{$toDouble: "$AMOUNT"}, 10000]}}}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VCJvvJBEef0)